Return the latest group of records inserted by specifically me into a table along with their ID in the table?
I have a table of Customers, named Customer with the following columns:



CustomerID
CustomerName
ContactNo
Address
DateCreated




1
Idola Steenson
438614198
Morena
2022-08-14 09:48:00


2
Graham Buckner
758531393
Panjim
2022-09-18 09:48:00


...
...
...
...
...



The CustomerID column is an identity, and I have a stored procedure that can take in a JSON file as the input parameter and insert multiple customers into the table. However, my goal is to allow the stored procedure to also display all customers who were last inserted into the table during the stored procedure along with their CustomerIDs within the procedure, I.E. basically inserting the customers into the table and telling me who was inserted and their place in the table.
ALTER procedure [dbo].[insertcustomer] (@json nvarchar(max))
AS
begin

select CustomerName, ContactNo, Address, GetDate() as DateCreated
into #d
from OpenJson(@json) with (CustomerName varchar(255), ContactNo bigint, Address varchar(255))

insert into Customer
select CustomerName, ContactNo, Address, DateCreated
from #d


select * from customer c
inner join #d
    on #d.CustomerName = c.CustomerName
where #d.DateCreated = c.DateCreated and #d.Address = c.Address
end

The code above allows me to get pretty far into my intended solution, as in it both allows me to insert multiple customers at once as well as displays all customers who were supposedly recently inserted. However, it does not account for Customers who may have the same name, and although there is where clause further eliminating possible problems by narrowing down the search to specific Date(s), it still doesn't clear up any potential issues in the future (e.g. 2 records with the same name, inserted within the same minute, with the same address (not mentioning ContactNo as it can potentially be null)).
I've been trying to find any posts or sites that might have a solution to this problem, but so far most of them are looking for a single recent record (would have worked if SCOPE_IDENTITY would save multiple identity changes).

If you want to get the details of the data you INSERTed why not use an OUTPUT clause?

If you don't have a good match between the to be inserted and the inserted customer, you can use the MERGE clause to insert and output the inserted and source data, since it allows one to access the source columns (which OUTPUT clause doesn't)

I'm still quite a newbie to SQL and hadn't realized the OUTPUT clause clears up any problems I was having above. Thank you for the assist!

You are really going to have to define how you want to match. What if they have the same name and address but inserted at different times? What about same name and address but different contactNo?
